# Android Manifest error - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have downloaded an sample about navigation drawer subject from this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7q0dzfhebbt4i7/ABSNavDrawer.zip

and there are a related video on youtube. the link is : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3QE74xRxp8

I have imported in eclipse the sample and I got this error. I searched on internet about this error but i didnt find any information. 
[image]

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual code. Not a picture. Are you sure you imported `ActionBarSherlock` correctly into the project?

Comment: There are 5 class and many lines. for the solution : I changed "AppTheme" instead of "There.SherLock.Light.DarkActionBar" and the error gone but I did not run on my phone the *.apk file.

Comment: You should paste this .xml code as part of the question. Not a picture. By changing to `AppTheme` you are not using `ActionBarSherlock` features.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloded & imported ActionBarSherlock from the following URL:http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html and set it as a library in its project properties. In your absnavdrawar application add the ActionBarSherlock library, clean the application and everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether u gave this line in your style.xml

```
 <style name="app_name" parent="android:Theme.Sherlock....">
</style>
```

and also check whether you have imported actionsherlock

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause by missing ActionBarSherlock Library.

Download and import ActionBarSherlock from this link http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html 
to eclipse. 
Right Click on ABSNavDriverProject->Properties->Android , under Library section choose Add 
and select the ActionBarSherlock lib.